# BigQuery Loading a table from uri

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a .csv file in a bucket, I want to load this file into a BQ table where the CSV headers match the table's columns.

I'm using the google-cloud-bigquery client library and the `load_table_from_uri` with a `LoadJobConfig`. This used to work fine, however supposedly randomly I am getting an error that the csv values are floats, the BQ table columns are integers.

However, upon checking the csv columns they are all integers. This is the code being used to load a CSV file now based on a trigger.

```
# dataset, table and bucket_name are defined before this code is being executed and work as intended.
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.schema_update_options = [
    bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION
]
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
 
try:
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset) 
 
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Something went wrong configuring the Google clients")
    raise e
 
def main(event, ctx):
    file_name = event["name"]
    file_uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}"  
    if file_name.lower().endswith(".csv"):
        job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    else:
        print("Input file is not a CSV file!")
        return
 
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(file_uri, dataset_ref.table(table), job_config=job_config)
 
    try:
        job.result()
        print(f"CSV file {file_name} loaded into {dataset}.{table} successfully!")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Something went wrong loading the CSV file: {e}")
        raise e
```

This results in

> Field AMOUNT has changed type from INTEGER to FLOAT

I've checked the CSV file and the AMOUNT column has no rows/values which could be considered integers. They are all natural numbers.

Tried setting `job_config.schema` to the table's schema, resulted in:

> 400 error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many erorrs. giving up. Rows: 0, errors: 2001. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details

I'm not quite sure where to look for the `errors` list/collection.

Here is a sample of the CSV file I'm trying to load into BQ:

```
APPLICATIONSTATE,APPLY_DATETIME,STATE_DATETIME,REQUESTEDAMOUNT,CONTRACTAMOUNT
INCOMPLETE,20220712 20:32:19.573,20221207 09:04:59.593,,
CANCELLED,20221012 08:41:12.669,20221208 09:24:21.596,23000,
CANCELLED,20221014 16:58:41.857,20221210 14:00:05.457,37000,,
```

[Some columns are redacted, the original CSV file's headers matches the table's schema.]

Comment: To add: Every field is NULLABLE in the table, empty values are not a problem.